# How can I add a class to iron router default template?

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

I've been searching all over and haven't really found an answer to this seemingly very simply problem.

I have an app that has a default template

```
Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'appLayout',
});

<template name="appLayout">
  <div id="container">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Then I have a new route called 'reservations'

```
Router.route('/reservations',{
name:'reservations',
  onAfterAction: function(){

  }
});
```

What I'd like to do is add a class to the default container that uses css transitions to animate background color from white to black.

What I've tried so far is *onAfterAction*

```
Router.route('/reservations',{
name:'reservations',
onAfterAction: function(){
    $('#container').addClass('black');
}
});
```

Does nothing, no errors, no anything. So I've tried

```
Template.reservations.rendered = function () {
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#container').addClass('black');
});
};
```

Which works, but flashes and creates routing problems. You can see the routing issues at [crawfish.meteor.com](http://crawfish.meteor.com/). How can I simply toggle a class after the template is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rendered` event:

```
Template.reservations.rendered = function() {
    if( ! this.rendered) {
        $('#container').addClass('black');
        this.rendered = true;
    }
};
```

Note that we check and set rendered. The Template instance then has a 'rendered' variable that we use to prevent re-triggering on re-render (which can run multiple times)